# Apache Log4j Unsupported Version Detection under Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, log4j

we have installed Visual Studio 2017 in our desktop. thru the Vulnerability scan, below issues raised. What would be the possible way to fix this issue. Shall we simply replace the Log4J jar file with the updated version in the below path ?

Path : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\SQL\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Extensions\Common\Jars\log4j-1.2.17.jar

Installed version : 1.2.17
Fixed version     : 2.16.0